# Django form action

Tags: python, django

I just started with Django and already scratching my head, I have a simple form with action set to null, On submit it goes to a url which I cannot find since I have to put a condition there as to which url should it hit.

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="">
            <h2>Education Details</h2>

             <form action="" method="post">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                {% if '/attorney-profile-wizard/additional-information/' not in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
                      <a href="{% url "attorney_edit" url_key %}"
                        class="material-button bg-red pl-2">Cancel</a>
                {% else%}
                       <a href="/attorney-profile-wizard/additional-information/"
                        class="material-button bg-red pl-2">Cancel</a>
                {% endif %}

                    <!--<a href="{% url "attorney_edit" url_key %}"-->
                    <!--class="material-button bg-red pl-2">Cancel</a>-->
                    <input type="submit" class="material-button" name="" value="Save Education">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Model:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    accolades = models.TextField(null=True)
    start_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_law_school = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    attorney = models.ForeignKey(AttorneyProfile, related_name='educations')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.attorney, self.degree)
```

views.py

```
class AttorneyEducationEditMixin(AttorneyEducationMixin, AttorneyEditMixin):
    form_class = EducationForm
    template_name = 'attorney/education/form.html'


class EducationCreateView(AttorneyEducationEditMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'educations.add_education'


class EducationUpdateView(AttorneyEducationEditMixin, EducationPermissionMixin,
                          UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'educations.change_education'


class EducationDeleteView(AttorneyEducationMixin, EducationPermissionMixin,
                          DeleteView):
    template_name = "attorney/shared/title_delete.html"
    permission_required = 'educations.delete_education'
```

I even tried to override the form action trying the following way:

```
{% if '/attorney-profile-wizard/additional-information/' not in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
                  <form action="{% url "attorney_edit" url_key %}" method="post">
                 {% else %}
                  <form action="/attorney-profile-wizard/additional-information/" method="post">
                 {% endif %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                {% if '/attorney-profile-wizard/additional-information/' not in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
                      <a href="{% url "attorney_edit" url_key %}"
                        class="material-button bg-red pl-2">Cancel</a>
                {% else%}
                       <a href="/attorney-profile-wizard/additional-information/"
                        class="material-button bg-red pl-2">Cancel</a>
                {% endif %}

                    <!--<a href="{% url "attorney_edit" url_key %}"-->
                    <!--class="material-button bg-red pl-2">Cancel</a>-->
                    <input type="submit" class="material-button" name="" value="Save Education">
                </div>
            </form>
```

This did not work and obviously is not the right way to do so. Where would I find the url for the action? I even checked `urls.py` file but it did not help much.

Comment: I would not want to hard code it even though I tried but it did not work

Comment: mean you dont know how put url in action and how it works?

Comment: I'm missing something.  Does the "target" URL depend on something you know when the form is being rendered, or does it depend on some user interaction with the page (e.g. which button they press)?

Comment: @ChrisCurvey There isn't any dependency. This is plaine copy pasted and its working fine the above form submits to a url name attorney/firstname-lastname/edit page but I cant seem to find where that url is given.